# How change a function to accept different types as argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, prototype

In the below eg, `myFoo` will accept an argument which is of type `Boolean`.

```
function myFoo(value:Boolean) { }
```

My Questions is, Is it possible to change the `myFoo` function to accept multiple `types` using prototype ?

eg,   `function myFoo(value:Boolean | string) { }`

Note: `myFoo` is a global function, which can't be edited directly.

**Updated**

Global function which is in different file,

```
export declare class MyGlobalClass<T> extends Observable<T> implements Observer<any> {
    myFunc(value: Boolean): void;
}
```

In my TS file,

```
this.myGlobalClass.myFunc('string');
```

But it throws type error. as myFunc accepts only `Boolean`. I need to fix this.

Comment: You can't change typescript types at runtime, because they aren't there when your code run

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? What is your use case? Are you trying to pass a string to the original function? Do you want to overwrite the global variable? Do you just want to redeclare the function's type?

Comment: yes you can do that and that will be called as loosely typed function declaration. Note that these types are only the aid for development. Once transpiled to vanilla javascript (the version which executes in the browser), this type info will be lost. 
It will be as good as `function myFoo(value){}`, but you'd still be able to check runtime type of the passed argument by using `typeof` construct.

Comment: I'm trying to pass a string to origin function with accepts only Boolean ,I need small patch  to fix asap.

Comment: @ImGroot - Im using typescript, it is not allowing me to do like you suggested.

Comment: `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: error went, but in spec it's getting failed.  Argument of type '"sometext"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Boolean'.

Comment: `this.myGlobalClass.myFunc('string' as any);`

Comment: I didn't suggest to use `function myFoo(value){}`. As I wrote, this is what it will effectively be transpiled to. Type information will be lost at runtime. What I mean by "lost" is to know the type of arguments that the given function accepts, By looking at the function object at runtime, we cannot say about what type of arguments it accepts. 
But when the function is actually invoked with an argument, we can look at the argument type using `typeof` then and do conditional execution based on the passed type. See my answer for details on how to implement the kind of patch you need.

Comment: You should use the type `boolean` instead of non-primitive type (Cf. [Number, String, Boolean, Symbol and Object]https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object))

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFoo(value: Boolean|string) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        //do string patch
    } else {
        //whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the type to be "any"

```
function myFoo(value:any) { }
```

Note that you will lose all the type checking that Typescript offers for this as you are basically telling Typescript that you want to allow your "value" parameter to literally be any type.